# Join along with sum and order by in Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm trying to perform the following SQL query using Eloquent:

```
select s.username, s.link, s.followers, sum(h.count)
from users s, views h where h.username = s.username order by h.timestamp
```

I'm aware of the `join()`, `sum()` and `select()` methods, however, how can I perform the `sum()` and `select()` together?

Answer (score 0):

To use a `SUM()` you will have to use `DB::raw`. Here is an example that should make your query work:

```
DB::table('users as s')
 ->select(DB::raw('s.username, s.link, s.followers, sum(h.count)'))
 ->join('views as h', 'h.username', '=', 's.username')
 ->orderBy('h.timestamp')
 ->get();
```